# Is possible to merge many .less into one before compilation?

Tags: symfony, less, assetic

I'm using LESS along with Assetic assets management in Symfony2, and lessc as a filter to complile .less to .css:

```
filters:
    cssrewrite: ~
    less:
        node: /usr/bin/node
        node_paths: [/usr/lib/node_modules]
```

I'm building an application using Twitter Bootstrap and in each .less file I want to use Bootstrap vars/classes to make my own custom definitions for specific modules of the application.

So I have, for example:

```
{% stylesheets filter="cssrewrite, less" output="css/less_compiled.css"
    'bundles/mopabootstrap/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less'
    'bundles/mybundle/less/module1.less'
    'bundles/mybundle/less/module2.less'

%}<link href="{{ asset_url }}" rel="stylesheet">{% endstylesheets %}
```

Now if I would like to use Bootstrap's vars and classes in module1.less and module2.less, I have to add @import [bootstrap_less_file] to each module file. It is not very elastic and it causes, that I have duplication of bootstrap definitions in each file.

I know that I can create one .less "index" file, which would import all needed files, and then compile it, but imho it is not elastic/symfony2/bundles approach, because then I loose of goods, which assetic gives me.

[edited:]
I would like to know if there is any solution to merge all files in {% stylesheet %} section and then send it to less filter/compilator.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Sorry made a mistake, because, I've added the post before I've written it to the end. (accidentally taping enter) Now I've edited it.

Comment: I've just seen, that inserting all the files as @import in one "index" file, do not give me ability to use one file in another one. So I cannot see any solution now.

Comment: What version of assetic are you running ? https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/issues/426 could be your problem

Comment: @TomToms, thank you for the link. I think it is a similar problem, but not the same. In the included issue there is a bug description, when I am looking for a feature :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### If you are running LESS 1.5

The latest version of LESS allows you to do an import as reference only. So this in the less files that use bootstrap...

```
@import (reference) bootstrap.less;
```

...will make it available for using as mixins, etc., but will not compile the code to css (avoiding code duplication).

Comment: Thank you for that. It solves the problem partially, but good enough. If someone knows bundle/library that modifies functionality of Assetic to work as I've described above, please give information, because that would be very useful.